# Enviar Input de texto em um FormData (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, input, formdata

Estou com um formulário de upload de uma imagem, mas também quero passa um campo de texto junto a imagem, a api esta funcionando perfeitamente e quando faço o envio pelo Insomnia ele cria tudo direitinho no banco, mas ao fazer as requisições no frontEnd ele só envia a imagem.

exemplo da service que estou utilizando

```
 importarArquivo(file:File, links: string ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // instanciando formData para utilizar no req
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();

    formData.append('imagens', file);
     formData.append('links', links);



    const req = new HttpRequest('POST',`${environment.apiUrl}/banners`, formData );


    return this.http.request(req);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente tente converter o arquivo para Base4:

```
static converterArquivoParaBase64(file: File): Promise<string | ArrayBuffer> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });
}
```

Após isto, na sua requisição, envie um json contendo o arquivo + propriedades que deseja:

```
salvar(link: string, base64File: string): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   let parametros = {
            "imagem": base64File,
            "link": "wwww.imagem.com"
   }
   const req = new HttpRequest('POST',`${environment.apiUrl}/banners`, parametros);
   return this.http.request(req);
}
```

Obviamente seu backend deverá tratar o arquivo base64 em conformidade com seu objetivo. Convertendo de volta ao arquivo original, salvando na base de dados ou qualquer outra intenção.